# Вектор указателей на виртуальные функции

Tags: c++, указатели

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли создать вектор указателей на виртуальные функции базового класса, чтобы вызывать их в цикле для каждого из объектов дочерних классов? Есть ошибочный пример, не могли бы Вы объяснить, где я допустил оплошность? Заранее благодарен!

```
 class Parent {
    public:
       virtual void func1()=0;  
       virtual void func2()=0;
 };

 class Child : public Parent{
    public:                 
       void func1(){//do something1}
       void func2(){//do something2}

 class SomeClass{
    public:
       std::vector<Parent*> vec;
       typedef  void (Parent::*ptr)();
       std::vector<ptr> unit;
       SomeClass{
          vec.push_back(&obj1);
          vec.push_back(&obj2);
          ptr func1=&Parent::func1;
          ptr func2=&Parent::func2;
          unit.push_back(func1);
          unit.push_back(func2);
        }
 Child obj1;
 Child obj2;
 void genfunc();                                                                
 };

    void SomeClass::genfunc(){
       for(size_t q=0;  q< unit.size();q++){
          for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
             vec[i]->unit[q]();
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: @VladD, нет, внутри SomeClass, внес соответствующие правки. Компилятор ругается на отсутствие члена unit в классе Parent.

Answer (score 5):

Вызов метода по указателю производится с использованием странного оператора `->*`.

У меня вот так работает (MSVC 2015):

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual void func1() = 0;
    virtual void func2() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(int n) : n(n) {}
    void func1() { cout << "Child::func1/" << n << endl; }
    void func2() { cout << "Child::func2/" << n << endl; }
    int n;
};

class SomeClass {
public:
    std::vector<Parent*> vec;
    typedef void (Parent::*ptr)();
    std::vector<ptr> unit;

    SomeClass(): obj1(1), obj2(2) {
        vec.push_back(&obj1);
        vec.push_back(&obj2);
        ptr func1 = &Parent::func1;
        ptr func2 = &Parent::func2;
        unit.push_back(func1);
        unit.push_back(func2);
    }

    Child obj1;
    Child obj2;

    void genfunc() {
        for (size_t q = 0; q < unit.size(); q++) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
                (vec[i]->*unit[q])();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass sc;
    sc.genfunc();
}
```

---

Обновление: C++ FAQ [рекомендует](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn) не заморачиваться с синтаксисом, а использовать `std::invoke`:

```
void genfunc() {
    for (size_t q = 0; q < unit.size();q++) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            std::invoke(unit[q], vec[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, сработало. Огромное спасибо, если я правильно понял, все дело было в низком приоритете указателя ->*, выражение следовало взять в скобки.

Comment: @ko4a: Пожалуйста! Да, скобки необходимы. Дописал ещё обновление в ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать!